# Better way to read in stream data without wrapping the whole thing in an empty try catch?

Tags: c#

Doing something like this at the moment:

```
try
{
    while ((bytesRead = clientStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) != 0)
    {
        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead) + Environment.NewLine;

        txtLog.Invoke(c => c.AppendText(message));
    }
}
catch
{

}
```

Which works but it's pretty ugly.

I know people are going to say not to catch all exceptions and to at least do something when an exception occurs but I'm writing a server application. If a user abruptly disconnections it doesn't matter. It doesn't need to be logged. Also, I never want the program to crash so is catching all exceptions really that bad? The program can still recover. After the while loop this code executes and everything is fine. Right?:

```
string clientIdentifier = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

bool clientRemoved = clients.TryRemove(clientIdentifier);

if (clientRemoved)
{
    listUsers.Invoke(c => c.Items.Remove(clientIdentifier));
}

tcpClient.Close();
```

Not really asking a specific question but more of wondering if this is fine and if not, what is a better way to handle a user abruptly disconnecting or any other form of read error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not really asking a specific question but more of wondering if this is fine and if not, what is a better way to handle a user abruptly disconnecting or any other form of read error?

Catch `IOException` and leave the others uncaught (the others indicate bugs in your code, and you don't want to swallow them). The `Exception.InnerException` tells you what happened, and, if the inner exception is a `SocketException`, you can check the `SocketException.ErrorCode` to get specific detail.

Note also that you can check `NetworkStream.CanRead` to see if the stream is readable (yes, the user could abruptly close after `NetworkStream.CanRead` returns `true` but before you execute the read). You should still wrap the `NetworkStream.Read` in a `try/catch` but note that you can avoid the exception if `NetworkStream.CanRead` is false.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Try, catch block, you can use Using block. But hey you cant get exception inside a using block though unless you explicitly use try catch again. 
Catching exception isnt really bad, but doing nothing and swallowing is bad.

But, as per your code, please use finally block to close all your objects streams rather than just living with catch. so that your app is safe and sound.